# Problems with addind xmlns namespace with SOAP and Java

Tags: java, soap, namespaces, attributes, xml-namespaces

I have to get a SOAP part like this one:

```
<PutMake xmlns="urn:PutMake">
    <x1/>
    <x2/>
    ....
</PutMake>
```

So I use this code to do it:

```
SOAPElement putMakeElement = soapBody.addChildElement(new QName("PutMake"));
putMakeElement.addNamespaceDeclaration("", "urn:PutMake");
// then adding child elements...
```

But the problem is I get the out SOAP like this:

```
<PutMake xmlns="">
    <x1 xmlns="urn:PutMake"/>
    <x2 xmlns="urn:PutMake"/>
    ....
</PutMake>
```

The "xmlns" parameter for PutMake I need is empty, but the parameter of the child elements have it set correctly, while they are supposed to not have that attribute at all.

I also tried using addAttribute instead of addNamespaceDeclaration, but the output is the same.

Why can it be like this?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `new QName("PutMake")` gives you a QName whose namespace URI is empty.  You need to use `new QName("urn:PutMake", "PutMake", "")` to get a QName with the namespace URI you require.